# Simple movie database error, python type uniterable

Tags: python

I am trying to design some code that accepts entry of movie titles and durations, adds them to an object which then is sorted and prints the three longest movies, it runs until the last line and then fails, how should I be doing it differently?

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, title, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.duration = duration


def get_movie_duration(movie):
    return movie.duration


class MovieCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.movies = []

    def add_movie(self, movie):
        self.movies.append(movie)
    
    def print_longest_movies(self):
        sorted(Movie, key=get_movie_duration, reverse = True)
        print('1. '+ str(Movie.title[0]) + str(Movie.duration[0]))
        print('2. '+ str(Movie.title[1]) + str(Movie.duration[1]))
        print('3. '+ str(Movie.title[2]) + str(Movie.duration[2]))

collection = MovieCollection()
while True:
    title = input('Movie title (or blank to finish): ')
    if title == '':
        break
    duration = int(input('Movie duration (minutes): '))
    Movie.title = title
    Movie.duration = duration
    collection.add_movie(Movie)


print('\n= Longest movies in the collection =')
collection.print_longest_movies()
```

Comment: "*it runs until the last line and then fails*" Fails *how*, exactly? Is there output that doesn't meet your requirements or expectations? Does it display an error? If so, why haven't you included it here as part of your [mre] in accordance with [ask]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print_longest_movies` function is confusing the difference between a list of objects, and their type.  `Movie` is not a list of things.  It's just the name of the class.  Plus, `sorted` RETURNS the sorted array.  It doesn't CHANGE the array.  You want:

```
    def print_longest_movies(self):
        self.movies.sort(key=get_movie_duration, reverse = True)
        print('1.', self.movies[0].title, self.movies[0].duration)
        print('2.', self.movies[1].title, self.movies[1].duration)
        print('3.', self.movies[2].title, self.movies[2].duration)
```

You have the same confusion when creating the list.  You want to create an instance of the class, not use the class name:

```
while True:
    title = input('Movie title (or blank to finish): ')
    if title == '':
        break
    duration = int(input('Movie duration (minutes): '))
    collection.add_movie(Movie(title, duration))
```